# getResourceAsStream returns null in one case but not another, with same classpaths

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, contextclassloader

I have two derivatives of the same application, say versions (A) and (B). They each contain projects:
(1) test-data-war, which has `target/test-classes/log4j.properties`, and (2) test-kernel, which has `target/test-classes/log4j.properties` and `target/test-classes/test.properties`.

When I run a specific jUnit test in (1), it calls a method in (2) which calls
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);` In (A), with `resourceName` as "log4j.properties", the result is not null with a path in (1), but with `resourceName` as "test.properties" it is null. In (B), with `resourceName` as "log4j.properties" it is not null with a path in (1) and with `resourceName` as "test.properties" it is not null with a path in (2).

Why is `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");` null in (A)? At first, I thought the classpaths might be different, but they are the same for both (1) and (2).

**EDIT:**
Here is what the .classpath file looks like for (1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes"    path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
     <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes"  path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
     </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes> 
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
        <attributes>
             <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" pat h="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Here is what the .classpath file looks like for (2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
     <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
         <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
          </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
         </attributes> 
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
     </classpathentry>
     <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
           <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes> 
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: You need to double check all your assertions, including the presence of those files in both JARs, and the classpaths.

Comment: I don't see the files in the target JARs of (A) or (B), but the ".classpath" files are the same across different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (B), there was had an additional dependency in eclipse on (2) that was causing `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties")` to NOT return null. It was actually supposed to return null (i.e. not find `test.properties` in (2)).

Answer (score 1):

Resources from the test classpath in module `test-kernel` aren't visible for module `test-data-war`. Modules only exports resources under `src/main/resources` when you add them as a dependency to another module.

The confusing thing is that Eclipse and Maven disagree here. In Eclipse, the whole classpath of a module is visible (also test resources). But when you run the same test in Maven, test resources will suddenly vanish. This is because Eclipse doesn't have a concept of "test classpath".

If `mvn dependency:tree` shows a difference, then you need to check the files `pom.xml` for the modules.

Comment: I think you have it mixed up. (A) and (B) are independent branches of an application. (1) and (2) are the projects that they each have. For (B), I see that (2) is a dependency of (1), but it doesn't seem to be the case for (A). I cannot figure out why since all the configurations seem to be the same for (A) and (B).

Comment: Do you see a difference when you run `mvn dependency:tree` with both?

Comment: (B) says it additionally downloads the POM from (2), but (A) doesn't! How do I change this?

Comment: Other than that, everything seems to be the same, except from some other jar versions. Is there a file I should look for in the (2) jar that could be different?

Comment: Yes, dependencies are specified in `pom.xml`.

Comment: The POMs in the project folder for (1) are the same and (2) are the same. Are there any other config files?

Comment: All the parent POMs seem to have the same relevant requirements.

Comment: The JARs are different, but they don't even contain `test.properties`.

Comment: What's the path of the file `test.properties`?